# Find out which features are collinear in a dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, statistics, statsmodels

I have constructed a model to predict the price of the house based on multiple features.

```
import statsmodels.api as statsmdl
from sklearn import datasets

X = data[['NumberofRooms', 'YearBuilt','Type','NewConstruction']
y = data["Price"]

model = statsmdl.OLS(y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)
model.summary()
```

How can I figure out which of these features are collinear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.corr()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) method.

Demo:

```
In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [28]: df['d'] = df['a'] * 10 - df['b'] / np.pi

In [29]: df['e'] = np.log(df['c'] **2)

In [30]: c = df.corr()

In [31]: c
Out[31]:
          a         b         c         d         e
a  1.000000  0.734858  0.113787  0.999837  0.067358
b  0.734858  1.000000 -0.523635  0.722485 -0.598739
c  0.113787 -0.523635  1.000000  0.129945  0.984257
d  0.999837  0.722485  0.129945  1.000000  0.084615
e  0.067358 -0.598739  0.984257  0.084615  1.000000

In [32]: c[c >= 0.7]
Out[32]:
          a         b         c         d         e
a  1.000000  0.734858       NaN  0.999837       NaN
b  0.734858  1.000000       NaN  0.722485       NaN
c       NaN       NaN  1.000000       NaN  0.984257
d  0.999837  0.722485       NaN  1.000000       NaN
e       NaN       NaN  0.984257       NaN  1.000000

In [33]: c[c >= 0.7].stack().reset_index(name='cor').query("abs(cor) < 1.0")
Out[33]:
   level_0 level_1       cor
1        a       b  0.734858
2        a       d  0.999837
3        b       a  0.734858
5        b       d  0.722485
7        c       e  0.984257
8        d       a  0.999837
9        d       b  0.722485
11       e       c  0.984257
```

Comment: This only gives you the correlation but not collinearity that involves more than two variables.

Comment: @Josef, good point, thank you! I didn't think of multicollinearity... What would you use in such a case? https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence.variance_inflation_factor.html ?

Comment: vif or QR for sequential identification. There is a stackoverflow answer for using QR in the singular matrix case, which I don't find right now. Finding which sets of variables are correlated is more difficult to define if more than two variables are involved because we only have a subspace, eg. two eigenvectors with eigenvalues close to zero. (There are several open, currently sleeping pull requests for statsmodels for multicollinearity measures, e.g. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/2380.)